# How to speed up the evaluation of a sum of incomplete Gamma functions?

Tags: plotting, functions, evaluation

We need to do a ContourPlot for the following function $H[x,y,n]$:

```
f[x_,y_,k_,n_,c_] := 
Gamma[c + (I/2)(x + I*y), k^2*(Pi/n), 
   k^2*Pi n]/(k^2*Pi)^(1/4 + (I/2)*(x + I*y));

g[x_,y_,k_,n_,c_] := f[x,y,k,n,c] + f[-x,-y,k,n,c];

H[x_,y_,n_] := 
 Sum[(3/2)*g[x,y,k,n,5/4] - g[x,y,k,n,9/4], {k, 1, n}];
```

The command for contour plot is:

```
n = 6;
ContourPlot[{Re[H[x, y, n]] == 0, 
Im[H[x, y, n]] == 0}, {x,-1,35}, {y,-1,35}, 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

The problem we are having is that for bigger $n$, like $n=12$, it takes too long (more than 30 min on my laptop (Intel i7 CPU, 16G memory) with Mathematica 11.3) to complete the plot.

***Question***
Is there a way in Mathematica to speed up the evaluation and the plotting of such function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: One thing to try is using `_?NumericQ` in all the definitions, i.e. `f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] :=  Gamma[c + (I/2) (x + I*y), k^2*(Pi/n), k^2*Pi n]/(k^2*Pi)^(1/4 + (I/2)*(x + I*y));` etc. With my AMD Ryzen 5 2600 it takes about 8 min for `n=12`. But `ContourPlot` is often very slow, Stephen mentioned this in his livestream in a sense that developers have to  finally "solve" this old known "feature" and speed up `ContourPlot`.

Comment: @Alx I will try it. Thanks!